# gmail new labels not showing when I try to send mail

Tags: firefox, gmail

I added 2 new labels to my gmail list.  When I try to send an email, the new labels are not showing.  The old labels appear to be still working.  The new labels do show in the contacts list and have the right people in them.

I have renamed the new labels, which did not help. I was using Firefox on Ubuntu, and I closed it down and cleaned out my cookies then restarted it.  That didn't help.  I tried Chrome and Firefox on Windows 7.  Neither of them work.

I have searched online for information about this, but am not finding anything helpful.  Can anyone suggest what the problem might be?